# ¿Cómo puedo evitar la duplicidad de los datos en una tabla?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, arraylist, jtable

Al momento de agregar otra vez a la tabla se me agrega y no se me ocurre hacer que no se agregue. Si a alguien se le ocurre como solucionar esto.

```
public void MostrarContenido() {
    int cont = 0;
    String data[][] = {};//creamos la tabla
    //nombre de columnas en la tabla
    String col[] = {"PLACA", "COLOR", "MODELO", "LINEA", "EJES", "PAGAR"};
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
    //llamamos a la tabla(JTabla)
    tablita.setModel(modelo);
    Ejercicio003Class d;
    //recorrer todo el registro
    for (int i = 0; i < Ejercicio003JFrame.contiene.size(); i++) {
        //almacenar 
        d = (Ejercicio003Class) Ejercicio003JFrame.contiene.get(i);
        //inserta fila (insertRow)
        modelo.insertRow(cont, new Object[]{});
        //muestra el valor de la primera comlumna d.get
        modelo.setValueAt(d.getPlaca(), cont, 0);
        modelo.setValueAt(d.getColor(), cont, 1);
        modelo.setValueAt(d.getModelo(), cont, 2);
        modelo.setValueAt(d.getLinea(), cont, 3);
        modelo.setValueAt(d.getNumEjes(), cont, 4);
        modelo.setValueAt(d.ejes(), cont, 5);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: public void ExisteDato() {
        mostrarDato();
        for (int i = 0; i < tablita.getRowCount(); i++) {//recorrido por todas las filas
            if (tablita.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(txtPlaca.getText())) {//verificamos si la placa ya está
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No puedes registrar 2 veces la misma placa", "Error, papu", HEIGHT);
                modelo.removeRow(i);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Ruberth , bienvenido a SO, por favor pon todo el código en formato texto y en la pregunta

Comment: La imagen no es necesaria, Ten en cuenta que para muchos es imposible de ver.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu **problema** es *evitar añadir filas duplicadas* (con la misma placa = clave primaria) entonces la **solución** es *verificar la existencia de dicha placa (en la jTable) antes de añadir la nueva fila*.

Se trataría de hacer un recorrido de todos los elemetos de la jTable y evitar la inclusión de una nueva fila si se cumple que getValueAt(row, 0).equals(//la placa de la nueva fila a  introducir). Algo así:

```
String = newRow.getPlaca(); //aqui obtienes la placa de la nueva fila a introducir 
boolean exist = false;
for (int i = 0; i < jtable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        s = jtable.getValueAt(i, 0).toString(); //la placa de la fila i-esima
        if (newPlaca .equals(s)) {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
}
if (!exists) {
    tablita.addRow(newRow);
}
```

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias, me ayudó :)